# ggplot2: Add coloring to a fix ggplot object

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors

I have a fix ggplot object (coming from a nice function that I do not want to touch). However, I would like to add some coloring afterwards, thus add new data. How would that be possible?

Here's a simple example.

```
gg <- ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)) + geom_point()
```

Now, I want object gg to be colored by Petal.Length,e.g. something like (but that's not working)

```
gg_colored <- gg + aes(col=Petal.Length)
```

to obtain:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to work with the way to handle aesthetics programmatically using [aes_string](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/aes_.html) or [aes_()](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/aes_.html).

The plot can be equally generated with

```
data(iris)
gg <- ggplot(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width, col=Petal.Length)) +
geom_point()
gg
```

Or

```
data(iris)
gg <- ggplot(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width))
gg_colored <- gg + geom_point(aes_string(col="Petal.Length"))
gg_colored
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I mean. Please consider gg as a object. I need something like gg + aes(col=Petal.Length)

Comment: Ok, now I got it!

Answer (score 0):

With the help of paoloeusebi's anwer, I also found a way to add a new colouring variable (instead of Petal.Length which is inside of iris)

```
mydat <- gg$data 
mydat$col <- rep(LETTERS[1:3], each=50) 
gg_colored <- gg + geom_point(data=mydat, aes_string(col="col"))
```